# Creating a 2-Dimentional ArrayList with diffrent datatypes

Tags: java, arraylist

So I want to create a kind of table using ArrayLists both for columns and rows. It's like an ArrayList inside another ArrayList. ArrayList of the columns(each with a different data type) where each column is also an ArrayList holding data of the type mentioned for that column.

I could really use your help about how can I make a table of this kind and how can I handle updating the info. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know exact types that will be used there?

Comment: they could be any of the types: Boolean, decimal, integer and string

Comment: What do you want to do with this structure?

Comment: Okay, then you should know that Java collections can contain only Objects, not primitives. So first you need to read about boxing/unboxing primitives into wrapper objects: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create such a table like this:

```
List<List<?>> table = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is what you were asking for, but I don't think that this structure is useful. You would have to create a new `ArrayList` for each column of your table. And the data in one column should always have the same type. Otherwise you could never get the data in a cell, because you would not know to what type it has to be casted. As an example look at this table:

```
name  | age
------+-----
alice | 25
------+-----
bob   | 30
```

Using the lists-sturcture, the table can be created like this:

```
table.add(new ArrayList<String>());
table.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Adding and accessing persons is not comfortable and error-prone:

```
table.get(0).add("alice");
table.get(1).add(25);
table.get(0).add("bob");
table.get(1).add(30);

String nameOfAlice = (String) table.get(0).get(0);
Integer ageOfAlice = (Integer) table.get(1).get(0);
String nameOfBob = (String) table.get(0).get(1);
Integer ageOfBob = (Integer) table.get(1).get(1);
```

This can be done much more effective if you create a class for the rows:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // Getters & setters

}
```

The declare tha table:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now adding and accessing a person is much easier:

```
persons.add(new Person("alice", 25));
persons.add(new Person("bob", 30));
Person alice = persons.get(0);
Person bob = persons.get(1);
```